# Where are my Application Settings when running on IIS

Tags: c#, iis-7

I have a deployed WCF application running on IIS 7.5 as a site.  One of the business dll's of that application (ABC.dll) has an application setting of type "connection-string".
I would like to change that DB connection string but can't find the right place to do it.
The ABC.dll.config in the Bin folder where the application dll's are deployed does not contain the actual connection string the application use at run-time.
How do I find that connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a WCF service running in IIS, you put the configuration in a `web.config` file in the root folder. This will contain all the settings that apply to your service. It is most likely that the connection string is being used from this file.

It is theoretically possible that if the settings are not in the web.config either, then they might be in the `machine.config` of the server on which you are hosting your WCF service. It is highly unlikely though that someone would store app-specific connection strings in this file but u never know sometimes.

Comment: 1. How do I access that setting from a DLL in that application.

Comment: 2. Where does that connection string value coming from now?

Comment: The same way you would if it were in abc.dll.config. For eg: if the string comes from appsettings and accessed by a key called Production it would still be `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Production")`